# In apex Application i want to change in application for selling_price(when we enter the price) in tabular form

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

In this query only for selling price when we enter the price of the item (I want that selling price colour should be displayed in in red in tabular form)..i have did this query in items in application of apex..if you are not clear in this please raise questions i will explain

```
select b.title||'@'||b.code||'@'||b.selling_price||'@'||b.language||'@'||b.qty r,
b.title||'@'||b.code||'@'||b.selling_price||'@'||b.language||'@'||b.qty r2
from  M_MASTER m left outer join book1 b 
on m.code=b.code and  m.category=b.category and m.title=b.title and m.PUB_TYPE=b.PUB_TYPE
where b.qty>=1 and b.f_year=:F115_CURRENT_YEAR
and m.PUB_TYPE=:P14_PUB_TYPE and ((m.category=:P14_CAT and :P14_CAT!='BOOKS' ) or
(m.Language=:P14_LANG and :P14_CAT='BOOKS' and m.category='BOOKS'))
```

Item name:A  CALL  TO  THE ETERNAL@OP-E0037@40@English@2

This is the format of tabular form,

```
BOOK:The book A  CALL  TO  THE ETERNAL 
CODE:OP-E0037
PRICE:40
LANGUAGE:ENGLISH
QUANTITY:2
```

Only selling price i want to highlight in red colour..please help me to recover from this problem..

Comment: This is a tabular form, with only 1 column with concatenated values? What do you mean with "format of the tabular form": the order of the columns (which can be gleaned from the query)? You want to put the "price" part in red? Always or conditionally? Why concatenate your values?

Comment: Hi Tom Thanks for your reply,Yes i want to change the price in red colour always..i concatenate because for selling book i have created the application in that application i make one page for selling book to make the customer bill transaction easy..in that i concatenate all in same line...i need that selling price in red colour..Is there is possible to attach screen shot if its possible means tell me..

Comment: best not to just leave your email here out in the open. If you have screenshots that can aid in determining your problem, then you'd best just add them in your question by editing it. I'm still not sure of what your setup and thus actual issue is and how we can best solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Formatting Report Output on an APEX Page

If you choose the format of the output region that displays your customer's book sale results, you can use the entire universe of HTML tags and formats (specifically the ones related to fonts, in your situation) to enhance your output.

### The APEX Page Design

Using an HTML enabled page region, anything you put under the HTML source definition will be interpreted and displayed as the HTML code indicates.

[image: HTML Page Output Example]

### The Page Display Output

This is how the above design looks.  As requested, the example shows how an HTML  tag can create the RED color effect for the PRICE value of the book.

[image: Book Sale Summary]

There are a number of ways to determine the current value of each book property (TITLE, QUANTITY, LANGUAGE, etc.)

Comment: Hi Richard,                                                      Thank you for resolve my problem,now its working..